# How to save a file that I upload through a form in Node.js

Tags: node.js, file, express, file-upload

I am buliding a web app through Express.js and I have a form to upload files. I need to save the files locally I do not know how to achieve this. I have tried to search on internet and all I can find is `fs.writeFile()` but this only works for saving plain text, so what if for example is a .pdf?

This is what I am using to choose the files:

```
<input type="file" name="myFile">
```

I handle the submits through JQuery:

```
$('#attachFiles').click(function(){
    $.post("/file", function(data){                
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use multer (a middleware) which is used to parse formdata. use it to save the file and images
Read this [Multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer)

Comment: Multer also support multiple uploads , i personally always use multer for such things

Comment: Thanks :) I have just checked it and I have a question. I don't use ```<form action``` to handle the submits, I use JQuery instead, so I have something like this: ```$('#attachFiles').click(function(){})``` Will it work in this way too?

Comment: I already know how to do a ```post``` in JQuery, I just don't know if it's possible to send the files through the post action in this case.

Comment: @AdriánT95 It doesn't matter how you submit your request as long as your request is valid. Make sure your request enctype is `multipart/form-data`.

Comment: @Dijkstra I mean, I have three files ```server.js``` (Node.js main file), ```userPage.ejs``` (the website) and ```javascript.js``` (JQuery code for userPage.ejs)... According to Multer documentation, I have to do something like this: ```upload.single('avatar')``` and I can do a post in JQuery like this ```$.post("/profile", function(data){});```. How am I suposed to send ```upload.single('avatar')``` to ```server.js``` which has the Node.js modules I'm using?

Comment: `upload.single('avatar')` this line means, your request body has field named `avatar` where multer will look for the file and store it.

Comment: Hi again... I am having an issue with Multer, Could you please check it out in case nobody has already helped me? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58605335/multer-is-not-saving-the-file-as-the-same-name-and-without-extension
Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

you need to send AJAX post request and in the post body add a formdata like

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('name_you_catch_on_server', JSON.stringify(your_file));
```

then Post this data with ajax request

```
$.ajax({
        url,
        method : 'POST',
        data:formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(data) {
            return data
        },
        error: function (err) {
        }
    })
```

Comment: Nevermind, I'm going to change it to ```<form post``` better. It seems hard to achieve  it in this way... Thanks anyway!